# Most efficient way to make duplicates unique in collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections, duplicates

I have a collection. And in this collection, if a duplicate is added, I want to append the text " - N" (Where N is an integer that is not used by a current item in the collection).

For Example, if I have the following list:

- item1
- item2

and try to add 'item1' again, I want the list to end up like so:

- item1
- item2
- item1 - 1

If I try to add 'item1' again, the list will then be:

- item1
- item2
- item1 - 1
- item1 - 2

Pretty straight forward. Below is my simple algorithm, but I'm getting a noticeable loss in performance when dealing with 10,000 items. Obviously that's going to happen somewhat, but are there better approaches to this? Couldn't find any similar question asked, so figure I'd see if anyone has ran into a similar issue.

```
Item copyItem = new Item();
string tempName = name;
int copyNumber = 1;
while(copyItem != null)
{
    copyItem = MyCollection.FirstOrDefault(blah => blah.Name == tempName);
    if (copyItem == null)
    {
        name = tempName;
        break;
    }
    tempName = name + " - " + copyNumber;
    ++copyNumber;
}
```

Comment: What happen if you add a new Item2 after item1 - 2, should it be item2 - 3 or item2 - 1 ? In a nutshell is the copy number global or per item name ?

Comment: You could keep a separate HashSet of the names for fast lookup to check existence instead of scanning the whole collection each time.

Comment: FloChanz, it should be item2 - 1 in that scenario. Per Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would firstly sort the values - thanks to this you only need to make a check with the previous value and not with the whole collection.

So it could look like this:

```
        List<string> values = new List<string> { "item1", "item1", "item1" };

        values.Sort();

        string previousValue = string.Empty; 
        int number = 1; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < values.Count; i ++) 
        {
            if (values[i].Equals(previousValue))
            {
                previousValue = values[i]; 
                values[i] = values[i] + "-" + number;
                number++;
            }
            else
            {
                previousValue = values[i]; 
                number = 1; 
            }

        }
```

Comment: Many people make it easy on themselves and use linq to objects to achieve this. It's good to know that there are still low-level programmers like me out there ;)

Comment: Suppose you had `{ "item1", "item1", "item1" }`. After processing the first two items you'd have `{ "item1", "item1 - 1", "item1" }`. Then the last one wouldn't match its predecessor so it wouldn't get renumbered properly.

Comment: you have missed the fact that I firstly sorted the list. Otherwise you are right- this approach would be a no-go. My algorithm with sorting makes it O(n) so very quick. On the other hand there is one drawback - you get the sorted values and sometimes you don't want to have them sorted (they need to stay in the original order).

Comment: I've edited my comment to take account of the sorting. The general point is still valid.

Comment: So basically whenever I add a new item, sort the list, and check if the previous value is the same, if so rename it by appending my special text above. Repeat these steps until the previous value is no longer the same. Sounds reasonable to me! thanks

Comment: Matthew Strawbridge, in my instance, the list starts empty, so anytime you add a new item, checking the previous should suffice. So bejger's answer seems to be a very viable one for my specific case.

Comment: Matthew: you are right! I have corrected the algorithm - now it works in all cases.

Comment: @jsirr13 This algorithm requires that you add all the values up front. You won't be able to add a few and get their new names, then add a few more (as your comments suggest you might like to do).

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `Dictionary<string, int>` to store the number of duplicates for a particular item. So a helper method would look something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> countDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(); // case sensitive!

string GetNameForItem(string itemName)
{
  var name = itemName;

  var count = 0;
  countDictionary.TryGetValue(itemName, out count);

  if (count > 0)
    name = string.Format("{0} - {1}", itemName, count);

  countDictionary[itemName] = count + 1;
  return name;
}
```

Alternatively, you could split up the operation into several methods if you didn't want `GetNameForItem` to automatically increment on retrieval:

```
int GetCountForItem(string itemName)
{
  var count = 0;
  countDictionary.TryGetValue(itemName, out count);

  return count;
}

string GetNameForItem(string itemName)
{
  var name = itemName;
  var count = GetCountForItem(itemName);

  if (count > 0)
    name = string.Format("{0} - {1}", itemName, count);

  return name;
}

int IncrementCountForItem(string itemName)
{
  var newCount = GetCountForItem(itemName) + 1;
  countDictionary[itemName] = newCount;

  return newCount;
}
```

It is important to note that if you are supporting deletion from the collection, you will have to update the count accordingly:

```
int DecrementCountForItem(string itemName)
{
  var newCount = Math.Max(0, GetCountForItem(itemName) - 1); // Prevent count from going negative!
  countDictionary[itemName] = newCount;

  return newCount;
}
```

You will also have to keep in mind what happens if you have two items, say "*Item A*" and "*Item A - 1*", then you delete "*Item A*". Should you rename "*Item A - 1*" to "*Item A*"?

Comment: I like the approach, but it would require too much refactoring on my end. Thanks for the input SiLo!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you need an iterator per value and not a global one. This code will do the thing.

```
        // Inputs for Tests purpose
        List<string> values = new List<string> { "item1", "item2", "item1", "item1" };
        // Result data
        List<string> finalResult = new List<string>();

        // 1 - Group by item value
        var tempResult = from i in values
                         group i by i;

        // We loop over all different item name
        foreach (var curItem in tempResult)
        {
            // Thanks to the group by we know how many item with the same name exists
            for (int ite = 0; ite < curItem.Count(); ite++)
            {
                if (ite == 0)
                    finalResult.Add(curItem.Key);
                else
                    finalResult.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", curItem.Key, ite));
            }
        }
```

Thanks to LINQ you can reduce the amount of code, next code will do exactly the same thing and should be also quickier because I use the ToList() method so the LINQ query will not have a deferred execution.

```
         // Inputs for Tests purpose
        List<string> values = new List<string> { "item1", "item2", "item1", "item1" };
        // Result data
        List<string> finalResult = new List<string>();

        values.GroupBy<string, string>(s1 => s1).ToList().ForEach(curItem =>
        {
            for (int ite = 0; ite < curItem.Count(); ite++)
            {
                finalResult.Add(ite == 0 ? curItem.Key : string.Format("{0} - {1}", curItem.Key, ite));
            }
        });
```